# Cloudflare blocking websocket connection

Tags: websocket, cloudflare

I have a node js web app that has a websocket server. When I connect to it from the same domain, the websocket connects but when I try to connect from a different domain it does not work. Is there any cloudflare settings that could be blocking this?

Comment: Provide more information if possible - what doesn't work, what errors you're seeing etc. Else it's hard to tell which cloudflare feature, if at all, is the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Changed minimum TLS version from1.3 to 1 because websockets use lower TLS version